# WebSocket 'message' with only one result on stream

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

I'm trying to get Deribit wss stream, but I'm getting only 1 incoming message.

isn't supposed the ws.on('message' update the incoming stream automatically?  Please tell me where I'm wrong.

Thanks

```
const WebSocket = require('ws');
const ws = new WebSocket('wss://www.deribit.com/ws/api/v1/');

ws.on('open', function open() {
    var args = {
        "instrument": "BTC-PERPETUAL",
        "depth": "1L",
    };
    var obj = { 
        "id": 5232,
        "action": "/api/v1/public/getorderbook",
        "arguments": args,
        //sig: restClient.generateSignature("/api/v1/private/subscribe", args) 
    };
    console.log('Request object', obj);
    ws.send(JSON.stringify(obj)); 
});

var bData;


ws.on('message', function incoming(data) {

   if(data.length > 0)
     {
        var obj = JSON.parse(data);

        bData = obj;

     }

});




setTimeout(() => {
        setInterval(() => {
           console.log(bData.result.asks[0].price + '   ' + bData.result.bids[0].price );
        }, 150);
}, 2050);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `getorderbook` endpoint is a one-shot action, the same as making a call to a REST endpoint.

You should be more explicit on what you're trying to do but I assume you want to get continuous updates on the order book. To achieve this you need to `subscribe` to a topic.

```
const params = {
  "action": "/api/v1/private/subscribe",
  "arguments": {"event": ["order_book"],
                "instrument": ["BTC-PERPETUAL"]}
}
```

Here's the relevant documentation: https://docs.deribit.com/rpc-endpoints.html#subscribe